# Asp.Net MVC RenderPartial different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

I got a view that inherits : `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyProjects.Models.MyAccountWrapper>>`

In this view I list data about the object MyAccountWrapper. This object contains a list of Account. Like this MyAccountWrapper.Accounts

What I would like in this view is to be able to create an account.

So I Try `<% Html.RenderPartial("../Account/Create"); %>`

But I got error about is not the good model. How can I deal with that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the appropriate model as second parameter when calling RenderPartial.

Comment: Do you have an example or a link of what you propose ?

Comment: RenderPartial has an overload that allows you to pass the model as the second parameter. It should be showing up in your intellisense.

Comment: Html.RenderPartial("../Account/Create", (IEnumerable<MyProjects.Models.MyAccountWrapper>)ViewData["Accounts"]); Where you have passed in the MyAccountWrapper into the View via ViewData

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a new controller and view that corresponds to `"../Account/Create"`.  This pins the URL for that action to a specific view.  The user will perceive this as a separate and distinct action, which in fact it is.  You can then return them to where they were by using a **[`ReturnUrl`](http://addinit.com/?q=node/7)** technique, if you wish.

In other words, you need a brand new page for this.

Comment: +1 @Melursus, this is the prefered approach and essentially how an MVC project works.  Seperation of concerns is a big factor in an MVC site.  You can avoid page bloat by using Partial Views and share them across the different actions.

Comment: The problem is I can't do that because it's in the spec. The designer design the page like what I describe and I have no choice.